# Restrict access to mercurial repository using Redmine

Tags: mercurial, redmine, git-flow, redmine-plugins

to project manage a mercurial repository, and track issues.

The workflow I want to use for the mercurial repository is branch based, i.e people are welcome to create branches and push their branches to the designated server. However I want to restrict access to the default(trunk) branch, so that all changes are merged by me into the default(trunk) branch.
This will allow control over things like code-review for each branch before merging it to the default(trunk) branch

Is there any way to use redmine to manage permissions and access to mercurial repositories?

I think I'm looking to do something like gitflow

Answer (score 0):

`Redmine` only allows you to work on a local clone of the repository as explained in their official guide [Redmine Oficcial guide#Mercurial-repository](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRepositories#Mercurial-repository) .
So i think you cant restrict the access to the repository on the web via `Redmine`.